# Join where one column is contained in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have a scenario where i need to join two tables on a condition which states if one column is part of other column, for example: if Table A column column1 is 'ABC' and Table B column column2 is '123ABC456', i have to check whether column1 is a part of column2 if yes there are matched otherwise no. I am trying to use "contains" but not able to figure it out how to use it. Can anyone please help me.

```
select B.Column2 from Table B join Table A on A.Id = B.Id 
  and Contains(B.column2,A.column1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`CONTAINS` is from Full-Text Search and unlikely to help this scenario.

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.TableA
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB
ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
AND TableB.Column2 LIKE '%' + TableA.Column1 + '%';
```